# VideoView can't play video

Tags: java, android

i want to play mp4 video (which is playable for android) using videoview but it can't play the video.

my video is in sdcard folder,

can someone help me,

here is my code:

```
final VideoView vd = new VideoView(AboutActivity.this); 

vd.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)); linevideo.addView(vd);

MediaController mediaController = new MediaController (this); 

mediaController.setAnchorView (vd); vd.setMediaController (mediaController); 

Uri video = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/media/vid.mp4");
vd.setVideoURI(video); vd.requestFocus (); vd.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp){
mp.setLooping(true);
vd.start (); 
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

at first try to change

```
vd.setVideoURI(video);
```

to

```
vd.setVideoPath(video);
```

and check are you add below permission in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that when declaring a videoView inside a layout; it sometimes doesn't show because is hidden behind some other component. To solve this you would have to add this line of code:

```
vd.setZOrderOnTop(true);
```

On other cases (although I'm not sure why this happens) it has worked for me to set the background of the videoView to transparent.

```
vd.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Comment: my code above is working if i'm loading uri url from online storage (ex.google drive, etc), but will give error if loading uri from local storage, like above, i wonder why....

Answer (score 0):

You are on right track, 
just use `mp.start();` inside `listener`

```
vd.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp){
        mp.setLooping(true);
        **mp.start ();** 
    }
});
```

Comment: mp.start or vd.start ?

Comment: mp.start(); use this

Comment: still nor playing, :/ dunno , but thanks for replying ;)